# Difference between "in doing so," "in order to," "in a way that," etc

Tags: difference, adverbs, conjunctions, phrase-choice, subordinate-clauses

I think you use the following phrases with the same meaning, don't you? Are any of them interchangeable? If so, when?

- in a way that
- in this way
- in such a way that
- such that
- so that
- in order to
- in order that
- in doing so

Comment: too many questions, and too many shaky suppositions. In your first list "in this way" does not belong. (It has nothing to do with a hoped outcome, only the manner of performing.)  in your last set, only the second and fourth are interchangeable. The others occur in different contexts, with different syntax and different meanings. If you want a usable answer, give examples in sentences and ask if they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

So you've listed a number of phrases, and you want to be able to distinguish fine shades of usage or meaning between them. I'll see if I can't help with that by using them in example sentences which are similar where possible and different where required. (I am not an architect, so don't take what follows as construction advice.) In each case, note how the rest of the sentence changes. The phrases are

1. in a way that

   in such a way that

   in this way

   in doing so

   in order to

   in order that

   so that

   such that

### Examples:

**1:** "I have designed the house **in a way that** allows air to circulate."

**2:** "I have designed the house **in such a way that** air is able to circulate."

**3:** "I have designed the house with large windows facing both east and west. **In this way,** I have allowed air to circulate throughout the house."

**4:** "**In doing so**" *would work equally well in the previous sentence. However, they are not completely interchangeable;* "in doing so" *implies that an active agent has done some "doing," while* "in this way" *does not.* "In doing so" *would not work well if substituted into the following sentence:*

"Crust forms in areas of sea floor spreading, and is destroyed in areas of subduction. **In this way,** the heat of Earth's interior is slowly allowed to escape."

*For some reason, I seem to be using a thermodynamic theme for these examples. Changing gears, the next sentence would not work as well with* "in this way":

"I shot the sheriff. **In doing so,** I signed my own death warrant."

**5:** "I have designed the house with large windows facing both east and west [**in order to** allow air to circulate throughout the house]."

**6:** "I have designed the house with large windows facing both east and west [**in order that** air may circulate throughout the house]."

*The subordinate clauses enclosed by brackets in the previous two sentences may come at the beginnings of their respective sentences if separated from the rest by a comma, per the usual comma rules.*

**7:** "I have designed the house with large windows facing both east and west **so that** air can circulate throughout the house."

*Inverting the previous sentence, as permitted in 5) and 6), would result in awkwardness.* "In order that" *is more formal than* "so that," *from which "that" is often omitted:*

"I poked a hole **so** air would leak out."

**8:** "Let Q equal the set of all p/q **such that** q is not zero and both p and q are in Z." [source: [Wolfram MathWorld]](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SuchThat.html)

*The last phrase in the list has a much more scholarly usage and tone than the others, owing to its origin in mathematics.*

---

See also:
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126885/in-order-that-vs-in-order-to

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer your last doubt

Suppose i live in a big apartment house alone. Now for one thing, all the domestic expenses are getting to be too much to bear for me and the second thing i've got very tired of living alone. I need some company. Now i decide to rent out two rooms in my apartment.

Following are the possible sentence that could come of from the above situation.

1. I rented two rooms in my apartment to two students. In doing so, my domestic expenses were shared and i even got two friends.
2. I am thinking of renting out two rooms in my apartment. In this way, i'll have my domestic expenses shared and i'll even get company.
3. My financial situation was getting to be very precarious. But i handled that situation in such a way that i saved on my domestic expenses and i also i got two friends.

   3a. I handled my financial situation in such a way that i killed two birds with one stone. (figurative use)